# Setting SCP on Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, ssh-keys

I have windows 7 and I installed Jenkins and git tools,but i want to use scp which will help copying files from linux server to windows server.

For this, I try to use Bitvise ssh to setup the ssh server and put in the linux server the public key to make it access without password.

But it still requires the password, i have no clue why.
Does anyone have done this before?